# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentTransaction android.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()'

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

When I try to dissmiss a FragmentDialog, my app crashes sometimes.
Here's the log:

```
Process: com.xxx, PID: 9981
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=xxxx flg=0x10 (has extras) } in xxxxxx
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:893)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentTransaction android.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:296)
    at android.app.DialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss(DialogFragment.java:277)
    at xxxxx.updateStatus(BaseAppCompatActivity.java:96)
    at xxxxx.access$000(BaseAppCompatActivity.java:43)
    at xxxxx$1.onReceive(BaseAppCompatActivity.java:79)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:883)
```

xxxxx.updateStatus(BaseAppCompatActivity.java:96)
this line is try to dismiss a DialogFragment:

```
mDialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
```

A DialogFragment is in my Activity.

```
private SimpleBlockedDialogFragment mDialogFragment = SimpleBlockedDialogFragment.newInstance();
```

So mDialogFragment is not null.

I show dialog like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mDialogFragment.updateMessage("xxx");
mDialogFragment.show(ft, "block_dialog");
```

And dismiss dialog like this:

```
mDialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
```

Sometimes, I show dialog only once, but dismiss more than once. But I don't think that cause a crash.

Here's the dismissInternal function in the DialogFragment:

```
void dismissInternal(boolean allowStateLoss) {
    if (mDismissed) {
        return;
    }
    mDismissed = true;
    mShownByMe = false;
    if (mDialog != null) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        mDialog = null;
    }
    mViewDestroyed = true;
    if (mBackStackId >= 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(mBackStackId,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        mBackStackId = -1;
    } else {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(this);
        if (allowStateLoss) {
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } else {
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

log tells me that getFragmentManager() return null. I don't know why this happened.
How to dismiss a FragmentDialog correctly?

**update:**
I try android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction, and still get an exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:196)
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss(DialogFragment.java:177)
```

Help~

Comment: @LonnieZamora this NullPointerException happened in the android framework.

Comment: What makes you think so?

Comment: @LonnieZamora at android.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:296). dismissAllowingStateLoss will call dismissInternal, and no params.

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentTransaction android.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference`

Comment: I finish my DialogFragments in a clickListener inside the DialogFragment itself, by simply calling `dismiss();`

Comment: @LonnieZamora So, this question is not  duplicate What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?  I need help.

Comment: public void dismiss() { dismissInternal(false); } just pass a false value to dismissInternal.

Comment: Use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragementManager`.

Comment: @jaydroider thank you. I tried. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` this may help.

Comment: thanks, I will try. But why do I use android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction instead of android.app.FragmentTransaction?